# Close device/socket in VxWorks

Tags: c, sockets, vxworks

Is there a way to close the device/socket in VxWorks programmatically?
Meaning say I have the devices `/tyco/0`, `/tyco/1` and `/tyco/2` and I want to close/shutdown `/tyco/1` and `/tyco/2`.

I would like to do something like `remove("/tyco/1")`. Something that would prevent even an `open("/tyco/1")` call later on in the code or from an outside source from opening the socket.

Answer (score 0):

All devices available to VxWorks are part of the device list. The device list is accessible using the [iosLib](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/iosLib.html).

I've used the following code a lot to remove devices to generate errors in order to test my programs:

```
DEV_HDR *pDevice;

pDevice = iosDevFind("/xyz", NULL);
if (pDevice != NULL)
{
    iosDevDelete(pDevice);
}
```

This works for all devices listed by the `devs` command which in your case will also work for `"/tyco"`. I doubt that you can inhibit open calls to `"/tyco/1"` and `"/tyco/2"` but allow calls to `"/tyco/0"` using that method since it works on "devices".

If `"/tyco/0"` is your serial interface to the VxWorks shell then the method from above will work. Because removing a device from the device list will cause all following `open` calls to that device to fail but will not close already opened devices...

Comment: Thanks Lukas looks exactly what I'm looking for. One question if I want to put this in a loop to close multiple devices what would I do with 'pDevices'? Set it to null on each loop, free it some how, ...?

Comment: @atomic928: `pDevice` is simply a pointer an entry within the kernel device list. You do not have to free it or set it to `NULL`. Also you shouldn't modify the memory `pDevice` points to...